Why does adding a new keyframe turn my old keyframe into the new keyframe?
File: 
I am completely new to blender and I have no idea what's happening with my animation. I keep trying to create two keyframes, but every time I try, adding the second keyframe turns the first keyframe into the second keyframe. I've seen other people with this problem on here, but I have no idea what the comments on them are talking about, so if anyone seeing this knows how to fix this and can explain it like you're talking to a monkey, that would be greatly appreciated!
Here's some pictures of what's happening if it helps:[

Hello, it would be helpful if you could attach your blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/

It seems you have autokey turned on, and this might be causing unwanted changes (it changes keypoints automatically when you move). It's the whit circle to the left of the play/pause/advance buttons in the timeline

Saying it changes keyframes automatically can be misleading. It simply keys down the changes you perform to the current frame your scene is at. If you make your changes meant for frame 20 while being at frame 1, you are overwriting the keyframe at frame 1. Always move to the desired frame first, only then make your changes. Or if you want to always manually write your keyframes, disable autokey entirely.

@DanielMöller "It seems you have autokey turned on" - Why do you think it seems like that? Just because the button is there? The Autokey button would be blue, not grey if it was turned on.

@GordonBrinkmann, autokey on is not blue, it's filled. Off is a hollow circle

@DanielMöller Yes, I see that the circle is filled. But I guess you are talking about version 4.1 and above where you have a hollow circle (but the button is still blue when turned on). In previous versions the circle is always filled, only the button color changes from grey to blue: autokey from 3.6.9 to 4.2.3. The filled light grey/white circle with grey/blue button exists since 2.80, up until 2.79b the filled circle was red, but the button color switched from grey to blue back then too. If yours is different, you might have a custom theme installed...?

DragonNuggets: The file you've uploaded to your question has no keyframes at all, the Timeline window is not even showing in your layout like in the screenshot. So if there would be anything to inspect it is all gone. But I doubt there was anything to see after it happened. Most likely you are doing things in the wrong order like Lauloque already suggests. The order is "select frame", "edit the location and rotation", then "add keyframe" as @DanielMöller says in his comment under this question: keyframes not working in Blender
